# How to follow webscraping progress with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm running a Python script with BeautifulSoup in order to extract Text, topics and tags from web articles. The website contains 210 pages, and each page contain 10 articles. (each article's url is stocked in a txt file)

I'm using the following code :

```
data = []

with open('urls.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for row in inf:
        url = row.strip()
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            
        if response.ok:
            try:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
                text = soup.select_one('div.para_content_text').get_text(strip=True)
                topic = soup.select_one('div.article_tags_topics').get_text(strip=True)
                tags = soup.select_one('div.article_tags_tags').get_text(strip=True)

            except AttributeError:
                print (" ")

                data.append(
                    {
                    'text':text,
                    'topic': topic,
                    'tags':tags
                    }
                )

    pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('text.csv', index = False, header=True)
    time.sleep(3)
```

My code seems to be corret but I ran this code and it has been running for several days now.
I would like to understand if it is an error that is blocking progress or if the process is simply very long.

To do this, I would like to know if it would be possible to add a "component" to my code that would allow me to track the number of urls processed in real time.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your code is written now, you are accumulating all the data in memory until it's all fetched. The easiest way to keep track of the progress without changing the code too much would be to just print either the current URL, or the number of the URL you're processing.

A better way that involves changing the code a little more would be to write the data to the CSV file as you are parsing it, instead of all at once in the end. Something like

```py
print("text,topic,tags")
with open('urls.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for row in inf:
        url = row.strip()
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

        # Getting the data you want...
        print(f"{text},{topic},{tags}")
```

If you are going with this method, make sure to escape/remove commas, or use an actual CSV library to produce the lines.